# How do I refer to the current directory in functions from the Python 'os' module?

Tags: python, path, working-directory

I want to use the function `os.listdir(path)` to get a list of files from the directory I'm running the script in, but how do I say the current directory in the "path" argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use os.curdir, and then if you want a full path you can use other functions from os.path:

```
import os
print os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
```

Comment: i ended up doing something a bit different in my won script, but this answer looks right

Answer (score 3):

You'd typically use `os.listdir('.')` for this purpose. If you need a standard module, the variable `os.curdir` is available.

Comment: i tried that, but i don't think it worked, it's possible i left the quotation marks off though, does it handle paths as strings kinda?

Comment: @bec: paths are strings, os.curdir is a string. there nothing specific about paths.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `getcwd()` function

```
os.getcwd()
>>> 'C:\\Python25'
```