# Get Path of File Relative Path of File that Imported Module in Python

Tags: python, import, module, filepath

I have this code in `my_program.py`:

```py
from my_module import do_stuff_with_file

do_stuff_with_file("hi.txt")
```

And this is `my_module.py`:

```
def do_stuff_with_file(fileName):
    print(fileName)
    # do stuff with the file
```

A file not found error arises when `my_module.py` is not in the same directory as `my_program.py`. This problem was solved using this code (`my_module.py`).

```
def do_stuff_with_file(fileName):
    fileName = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.modules['__main__'].__file__), fileName)
    print(fileName)
    # do stuff with file
```

The issue arises when `my_program.py` is imported by a file in a different directory.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The problem is not clear. Could you restate the observed behavior and the desired output ?

Comment: @Lenormju, I have tried to clarify the problem :). If you need an example, look at https://github.com/kethan1/playsound2, and run the tests with pytest

Comment: Is this a file that is delivered with your project is and supposed to be relative to the module, or should this code work with any file anywhere? Since `my_program.py` used a relative path name, its relative to whatever `os.getcwd()` says is the current path. If you run from the command line, its the shells current directory. Otherwise its..., well, who knows?

Comment: Its weird that `do_stuff_with_file` would try to fix a relative path name. Shouldn't it work with anything? Likely you want any path manipulation in `my_program.py`. We need to know where you expect this file to be.

Comment: @tdelaney the `my_module.py` might be in a subdirectory or parent directory of `my_program.py`. Fixing the path fixes this (using `sys.modules['__main__'].__file__`). When running with pytest for example (or importing `my_program.py` from another python file), the issue occurs.

Comment: @KetZoomer - Only if the file is supposed to be in the same directory as the main scirpt. That's why I asked. Its still odd that a module would look for files in the directory holding the main script. In an installed execution environment, scripts are tucked away into directories such as /usr/bin and are isolated from the data files that are processed. This is only a fix if you specifically want to reference files in the scirpt's directory. That's the question I asked. Your comment didn't answer that question.

Comment: @tdelaney, ah, sorry for not being clear. The file (in this case `hi.txt` but it could be anything) is the same directory as `my_program.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following file hierarchy :

```
stack_overflow/
├─ q67993523/
   ├─ my_module/
   │  ├─ __init__.py
   ├─ 67993523.py
   ├─ hi.txt
```

With the following file content :

```py
# 67993523.py
from my_module import do_stuff_with_file

do_stuff_with_file("hi.txt")
```

```py
# my_module/__init__.py
def do_stuff_with_file(filename):
    print(f"{filename!s} content is :")
    with open(filename, "rt") as file:
        print(file.read())
```

and the file `hi.txt` :

```py
Hello !
```

When I run `C:\path\to\python.exe C:/stack_overflow/q67993523/67993523.py` (with the path to `q67993523` included in my `PYTHONPATH`), with my current directory being `q67993523/`, I get :

```
hi.txt content is :
Hello !
```

But if I change my current dir to `q67993523/my_module/` and execute the exact same command, I get :

```
hi.txt content is :
Traceback:
[...]
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hi.txt'
```

because relative to the current working directory `q67993523/my_module/` there is no file `hi.txt`, the file would be `../hi.txt`.

I think what you are doing is an instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

What you are trying to achieve is to find a file given its name but not the location. It is very difficult to do, prone to error, and would include lots of *hacks* to work.
I don't think it is **actually** what you want to do. What you want to do, I presume, is not to search for files but just to use them. So you should not lose the precious information of their location.

For example, in your main script (mine is `67993523.py`), you know that the file is right there, in the same directory. But if you just send `hi.txt`, because the function don't know the file location of the code that called her, it does not know where to search for the file.
Instead, give the **complete file location**, namely the absolute path.

If I change my main script to :

```py
# 67993523.py
from pathlib import Path

from my_module import do_stuff_with_file

the_directory_of_this_pyfile = Path(__file__).parent
do_stuff_with_file((the_directory_of_this_pyfile / "hi.txt").absolute())
```

And run it with my current directory being `q67993523/`, I get :

```
C:\stack_overflow\q67993523\hi.txt content is :
Hello !
```

And when I change my current directory to `q67993523/my_module/`, I get the same thing :

```
C:\stack_overflow\q67993523\hi.txt content is :
Hello !
```

The difference is that in your script, the `hi.txt` filename assumes that your current working directory is `q67993523/`. If you have a different current working directory (because Pytest, because running the script for anywhere you want, ... see the comment from @tdelaney) then there is no `./hi.txt` file, so it will fail.

I encourage you to learn on the topic of [current working directory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd)
and how to express the [current Python file directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758855/how-do-i-refer-to-the-current-directory-in-functions-from-the-python-os-module).

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I knew I probably couldn't get away with a relative path, but using pathlib seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: @KetZoomer the main thing to understand is the relation between the `current working directory` which is the start of relative paths, and absolute paths (which start at the root of the drive). Relative paths are shorter, but cause problems when the cwd is not under full control. Hence I tend to favor absolute paths, which work in every case.